# How do I close an conversation in Yammer

Tags: yammer, yammer-api

I have a very special requirement from a customer. He wants to close conversations in Yammer from a Power Automate flow.

There is no ready functionality in PowAutomate to close the conversation so I assume that I need to do a REST call. But then the next problem arised. I dont find anything in the documentation how to do that. So my question is:

How the heck do I close a conversation in Yammer via REST? What endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this not a supported API operation right now which is why it's not documented.

If you do some spelunking in the HTTP request traffic of the web application, or mobile apps, you might be able to find an undocumented call. Using this would be unsupported though. Whether you proceed depends on your risk profile. It might be useful to prototype and submit a feature request to Microsoft to see if it can be supported.